# 'map' object is not subscriptable (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
N,M = map(int, input().split())
a = map(int, input().split())
b = [0] * N
c = 0
d = 0
e = []
for i in range (M):
    b[a[i]] += 1
for i in range (N + 1):
    if b[i] >= c:
        c = b[i]
        e[d] = i
        d += 1
print(*e)
```

В строчке b [a[i]] почему-то вылезает ошибка, хотя b - массив созданный из нулей и в принципе мне казалось, что все должно работать

Comment: В третьем питоне вызов map возвращает не готовый список, а "ленивый" генераторный объект. Это позволяет экономить память и выполнять долгие вычисления не сразу большим куском, а по мере необходимости. Поэтому если вам нужен всё-таки список, то после map нужно ещё явно применить list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При вызове `a[i]` оператор `[i]` транслируется в вызов метода `a.__getitem__(i)`.

У объекта типа `map` не существует такого метода:

```
In [14]: type(a)
Out[14]: map

In [15]: a.__getitem__(0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-82c105a3393c> in <module>
----> 1 a.__getitem__(0)

AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Оберните все вызовы `map()` конструктором `list()`:

```
N,M = list(map(int, input().split()))
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
```